# Cold treatment for kernel germination while fighting fungus

Tags: seeds, germination, growing-medium

I try to germinate stone fruits often in the fridge, inside a bag of peat moss. When I prepare the peat medium I wet it with rain water, but often the seeds/kernels rotten. I was wondering if I could soak the seeds in 10% bleach solution or even use the same solution to wet the peat moss instead of rain water. Could the bleach at that concentration hurt the germination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of water in the sealed bag is critical; very little is needed. Also peat might be a poor choice for the packing material - peat is good at holding quite a lot of water, but what is needed is just a light spritzing which would cover the exterior surface of an inert material like perlite or sand. Using bleach could be counter productive - if it is used make sure to allow the chlorine gas to fully escape before sealing the bag.

Answer (score 0):

Peat and rain water are not sterile, so anything which can grow at the fridge temperature (including moulds) will do so.

While the seeds/kernels are cold they are dormant, so they don't need water. Try just sealing them "dry" in a plastic bag.

Comment: I believe he is trying to sprout them in the refrigerator.

Comment: Indeed @blacksmith37, I'm trying to germinate seeds that require some cold stratification.